# localhost is not loading project files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Working on laravel project,everything was fine,just faced this error and localhost is not loading my project files.

```
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xa mpp\htdocs\test\storage\framework\views\35e08ec6154c6787dbf8a82598cafe07f487d9a9.php on line 1 [Fri Oct 5 23:56:38 2018] 
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xa mpp\htdocs\test\vendor\symfony\debug\Exception\FatalErrorException.php on line 1 [Fri Oct 5 23:56:38 2018] 
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 69632 bytes) in Unkno wn on line 0
```

here is the image of what the server says.

[image]

Comment: where is the image?

Comment: Why an image? Can't you just paste that error message as text here?

Comment: @ kerbholz,@partik just click on that link ,it will show you the image,just updated the post

Comment: Why not just paste it as text, so others can easily copy/paste it and search the web? The message clearly says you exceed the memory limit.

Comment: well I guess one can easily judge by looking at the image,I'll keep in mind that next time :(

Comment: Quick dirty fix `php -d memory_limit=1024M artisan serve`. This is rarely occurred on fresh Laravel project. So I think there's a bad code here.

Comment: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xa
mpp\htdocs\test\storage\framework\views\35e08ec6154c6787dbf8a82598cafe07f487d9a9.php on line 1
[Fri Oct  5 23:56:38 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xa
mpp\htdocs\test\vendor\symfony\debug\Exception\FatalErrorException.php on line 1
[Fri Oct  5 23:56:38 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 69632 bytes) in Unkno
wn on line 0

Comment: here is the link for you @kerbholz

Comment: did you tried `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` ?

Comment: @mehmoodkhan please add all relevant information (such as example code and error messages) to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Locate your php.ini file by writing `php --ini` in the console (in my case it is located in `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/`). Open php.ini, locate the line that sets memory_limit, and set it equal to `-1`(`memory_limit=-1`).

> sudo vi /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini memory_limit = -1

Sorry, I didn't see it.

Window: find your php.ini local

explame:`C:\PHPTutorial\php\php-7.1.13-nts\php.ini`
Find and update
`memory_limit = -1`

Comment: How could one run `sudo vi` on a Windows system?

Comment: This will get you running, but it's not going to resolve your problem. If you've got a memory problem, this will just disguise it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you're exceeding your memory limit. You could increase it in php.ini (memory_limit) but you should really try to work out what change you've just made which is causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah,I changed that many times in php.ini file to different values ,still facing same problems.the maximum limit there was about 128MB.I tried 128MB,512 and 64 as well,nothing happened

Answer (score -1):

If you install it through Homebrew it seems that [Composer package](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2704#issuecomment-56364138) is not up to date.

If this is your case you can run from command line `composer self-updat`e and retry.

also set your memory in php.ini file and then try to [install](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-laravel-5-4-localhost/) again.

Comment: Have you even read the error message? It complains about an error in `C:\xampp`, that looks like a Windows system which is not capable of running Homebrew after all